Acoustic Field Theory examples and resources
Does anyone know of any good resources to study Acoustic Field Theory? Mainly focused on reflection and refraction of acoustic waves. I currently have online versions of B.A. Auld's book on Acoustic Fields and Waves in Solids, however, are there any additional sources on this subject?
Especially because part II has pages that don't have the correct resolution, which ruins any figures trying to explain the subject:

